# What is CellRendererPane for?

Tags: java, swing

The class `javax.swing.CellRendererPane` "is inserted in between cell renderers and the components that use them" and "just exists to thwart the repaint() and invalidate() methods which would otherwise propagate up the tree when the renderer was configured."

That's what the JavaDoc tells me, but what does it mean? How is it used, and what would happen if the `repaint()` and `invalidate()` were instead allowed to propagate up the tree? Concrete examples are particularly welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means it is inserted in the middle of the component tree (rooted in the top level window) and will eat certain events e.g. repaint & invalidate to prevent their propagation up the component containment hierarchy.

Why? Because repaint and invalidate are potentially expensive events to process; it is not necessary in this case; and a simple component (the pane) can trivially filter them.

If events were to propagate, then every component would needlessly recompute their layout (invalidate) and redraw (repaint) themselves.

Comment: Can you give an example of a case where this repainting would otherwise occur unnecessarily?

Comment: Well, according to them "when the renderer [is] configured".  I merely explained the notion of containment tree of components, and how events propagate up and can be eaten/filtered (if handled).  And that these 2 specific events are (relatively speaking) computationally expensive.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly this is useful when a change in a component is known not to have any effect on the appearance of the container it is in, or any of the other components in that container, and especially when there are many such components (such as cells in a table) so that recomputing the layout and repainting would be time-consuming. Is that correct? I guess I need to go and read the tables section in the Swing tutorial.